# Executing Caml Query without ExecuteQueryAsync and "The collection has not been initialized...." Error

Tags: list, javascript, caml

I have been trying to use Caml Queries to filter SharePoint lists and return the number of times that a given value is found in the SharePoint list. Here is the part of my code that I've been having issues with:

```
...
var camlString = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='School'/>" + 
        "<Value Type= 'Text'>" + [STRING1] + "</Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='StaffingStatus'/>" + 
        "<Value Type= 'Text'>" + [STRING2] + "</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>";  

try{
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {retrieveListItems(camlString); }, "sp.js");

}catch(err){
     alert(err.message);
 } 



 }

 //function to pull specific items from a list using a CamlQuery
 //caml parameter takes in the caml query as a string
function retrieveListItems(caml) {
try{
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('[LIST NAME]');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

camlQuery.set_viewXml(caml);

this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(School, Staffing_x0020_Status)');

 var listItemInfo = '';

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

//More code to iterate through the list and count the total number of records
...
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message:

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or
>   the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
>   requested.

This seems to be triggered by the last line in my code snippet above ("collListItem.getEnumerator();"). When I researched this online, I found that the common solution to this problem was to add "Include([FIELD NAMES])" to my clientContext.load statement. I did this, but I am still receiving the error message.

I don't have this issue when I include     `clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));`
in my code before "varlistIemInfo ='';" and include all the code after it in a separate "onQuerySucceeded" function. However, I would rather not use this solution since it executes asynchronously and makes my function difficult to use inside of a loop.

Does anyone know of a way that I could get this to work?

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Comment: `load()` doesn't actually _load_ the data, but marks the data as _needs to be loaded_. `executeQueryAsync()` actually loads all the data that has been marked as needs to be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how JavaScript client object model works. After loading, you need to execute `clientContext.executeQueryAsync` in order to get results back. However, if you don't like the `asynchronous` execution and want `synchronous` execution then you can use callbacks of deferreds. An example using JavaScript callbacks:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //don't exectute any jsom until sp.js file has loaded.        
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', prepareTables);
    });

function prepareTables() {
    getItemsWithCaml('External User Account Request',
            function (camlItems) {
                var listItemEnumerator = camlItems.getEnumerator();
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    console.log(listItem.get_item('Title'));
                } console.log('Completed table prparation.');
            },
            function (sender, args) {
                console.log('An error occured while retrieving list items:' + args.get_message());
            });
}    

function getItemsWithCaml(listTitle, success, error) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var camlItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(camlItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                success(camlItems);
            },
            error
        );
};
```

An example using deferreds:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //don't exectute any jsom until sp.js file has loaded.        
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', prepareTables);
    });    

function prepareTables() {
    getItemsWithCaml('External User Account Request').then(
            function (camlItems) {
                var listItemEnumerator = camlItems.getEnumerator();
                while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                    console.log(listItem.get_item('Title'));
                } console.log('Completed table prparation.');
            },
            function (sender, args) {
                console.log('An error occured while retrieving list items:' + args.get_message());
            }
        );   
}    

function getItemsWithCaml(listTitle) {
    //use of $.Deferred in the executeQueryAsync delegate allows the consumer of this method to write 'syncronous like' code
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();        
    var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(items);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this,
            function () { deferred.resolve(items); }),
        Function.createDelegate(this,
            function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); }));

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

See this for more information: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-using-deferredspromises-or.html